# re-sequencing a column of numbers based on a set value, R

Tags: r

I have a column of numbers that need to be re sequenced starting from 1, for example:
 column with numbers: 226 227 227 227 228 228 229 229 ...... so on

I would like to re sequence so that: 226 changes 1, 227 changes 2, 227 = 2, 227 = 2, 228 = 3, 228 = 3, 
 229 = 4, 229 = 4  ....... and so on

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Current</th>
    <th>Desired</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>226</td>
    <td>99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>227</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>227</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>227</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>228</td>
    <td>101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>228</td>
    <td>101</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>229</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>229</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>229</td>
    <td>102</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `df1$Current - df1$Current[1] + 99`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `as.numeric` + `factor` like below, i.e.,

```
r <- as.numeric(factor(v))
```

such that

```
> r
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4
```

**DATA**

```
v <- c(226, 227, 227, 227, 228, 228, 229, 229)
```

Comment: All solutions worked used factor(v) from ThomasIsCoding. thank you

Comment: @bonjih Thanks! If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can subtract the `min`imum or the `first` element of 'Current' and then add 99 to it

```
df1$Desired <- df1$Current - df1$Current[1] + 99
df1$Desired
#[1]  99 100 100 100 101 101 102 102 102
```

Or if it needs to be resequenced from 1

```
df1$Current - df1$Current[1] + 1
```

Or use `match`

```
match(df1$Current, unique(df1$Current))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Current = c(226, 227, 227, 227, 228, 228, 229, 229, 229))
```